# Manage User Roles based on Projects in rails and mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid6

I am using rails and MongoId.
I have 3 models - User, Project and Role.
I want to manage user roles based on projects.
For example: user1 has assigned to 2 projects, for project1 user1 may be admin, for project2 user1 may be a Quality Analyst.

How I can achieve this when using mongoid in rails.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) and add multiple roles to user and in `Project` model filter if a user has a specified role and manage it.

Comment: Hi Uday, thanks for your solution, just now I went through it, looks easy and simple. My question is, will this work for mongoid? I am not using Active Record, I am using mongoid.

Comment: yeah! there is documentation for `mongoid` too check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot Uday, Rolify suits perfectly for my requirement.